# Searching in a shared folder through iis

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have written a web app in which the user is able to search in a shared folder for files and then the file that they chose will be displayed in the browser.

All works fine when I run the app through Visual Studio.

But if I try to run it through IIS I get an error 500 (Internal Server Error) when the JSON which is in the shared folders executes.

Is there any permission limitation? Will I run it through the VS it uses my credential but not while I run it through IIS? Maybe the shared folder must have read access for the IIS_IUSR group? Do I get that right?

```cs
public JsonResult GetFiles(string MCodeID)
{
  if (MCodeID == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(MCodeID));
  }

  List<Files> filelist = new List<Files>();
  //Searching Files in //192.168.1.191
  string path = @"\\192.168.1.191\Materials Project\";
  string searchPattern = MCodeID + "*";
  DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(path);
  if (fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any())
  {
    foreach (var file in fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
      var changeSlash = file.FullName.Replace('\\', '/');
      var filepath = changeSlash.Replace("//192.168.1.191/Materials Project", "");
      filelist.Add(new Files
      {
        FCodeID = filepath,
        FDescr = file.Name + " - " + Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(file.Length) / (1024*1024)), 2) + " MB",
        FSize = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(file.Length) / (1024 * 1024)), 2)
      });
    }
    filelist.Insert(0, new Files { FCodeID = "0", FDescr = "--Select File--" });
    return Json(new SelectList(filelist, "FCodeID", "FDescr"));
  }
  else
  {
    filelist.Insert(0, new Files { FCodeID = "0", FDescr = "--No File--" });
    return Json(new SelectList(filelist, "FCodeID", "FDescr"));
  }
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MCodeID").on("change", function () {
      var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Materials/GetFiles";
      var ddlsource = "#MCodeID";
      var items = "<option value='0'>--Select File--</option>";
      $("#FCodeID").html(items);
      var items = " ";
      $("#pdfviewer").hide();
      $(".loading-eclipse").show();
      $.getJSON(url, { MCodeID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
        $("#FCodeID").empty();
        $.each(data, function (i, file) {
        if (file.value.includes("in Use"))
          items += "<option value='" + file.value + "'" + "style='background-color:orange;'>" + file.text + "</option>";
        else
          items += "<option value='" + file.value + "'>" + file.text;
      });
      $("#FCodeID").html(items);
      $(".loading-eclipse").hide();
      $("#FCodeID").show();
    });
  })
})
    </script>
```

Is there any way to use the users credentials when the app is executed through IIS?

Comment: which identity and authentication you are using?

Comment: I use ApplicationPoolIdentity and Anonymous Authentication

Comment: try to give permission for application pool identity to the shared folder.

Comment: from the security tab at shared folder I add user ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Comment: try to set iis_iusr and iusr permission to that shared folder.

Comment: Thanks I try that and let you know

Comment: I set iis_iusr and iusr permission to the above shared folder, but I still get the same error.
GET http://10.10.10.187:8003/Materials/GetFiles?MCodeID=xxxxx.xx 500 (Internal Server Error)
and at  send @ jquery.js:9837
callback = callback( "abort" );
try {
    // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
    xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
    } catch ( e )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above error by providing a user with full access to the share folder and not just read permission.
Thanks @Jalpa for your help.